# Regex match the prefix and suffix of strings ending with numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Using a regex I would like to find out the prefix and suffix of string like these:

```
T12231 should match ['T', '12231']

Acw2123 should match ['Acw', '2123']

121Ab should match ['121ab', null]

1213 should match [null, '1213']
```

Matching only the numbers at the end of the string is easily done with this regex `/([0-9]+)$/g`.

Matching everything from the beginning of the string up to this point I did not manage to do. The closest I got was for the 1st group to match everything but the last number with `/^(.*)([0-9]+)$/g`.

Comment: The first group could be "anything that's not a number" or, from your examples, "any upper/lower case alphabetic character".  `\d` is the same as `[0-9]` and `\D` is the same as `[^0-9]` so you could look for something like `/^(\D*?)(\d+)$/` ... the `/g` is pointless if you are using `^` and `$` together because that will match the whole line.

Comment: And what does `123Ab345` match ?

Comment: @sln ['1234Ab', '345']

Comment: Hmm, then it is a situation where the regex needs an assertion to guarantee it does not match the empty string. `^(?=.)(.*)(\d*)$` Nah, I'd say this can't be done ... unless it is forced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the first capture group lazy, `.*?` so it matches as short as possible, i.e, make the second capture group as long as possible:

```js
var s = ["T12231", "Acw2123", "121Ab", "1213"];

console.log(
  s.map(x => x.replace(/^(.*?)([0-9]*)$/,  "$1 $2"))
);
```

Push the split result into an array:

```js
var s = ["T12231", "Acw2123", "121Ab", "1213"];

var arr = [];
s.forEach(x => x.replace(/^(.*?)([0-9]*)$/, (string, $1, $2) => arr.push([$1, $2])));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: this is what I've been missing. The lazy evaluation does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right. Try using this:

```
var re = /^(.*?)(\d+.*)$/g;
var groups = re.exec(your_string)
```

Comment: this does matches properly. The 2nd group allows for any characters at the end. '123Ab456' gets matches as ['', '123Ab456']

Comment: isn't it supposed to happen?

Comment: No, I would expect in this case to get ['123Ab', '456']. The problem I'm trying to fix is generate a next string that for '123Ab456' would be '123Ab457'. So I need the last number in the string, and the rest of it so I can stitch them back together.

Comment: @tsokv In that case, and with your `121Ab should match ['121ab', null]` I assume becomes `121Ab1` ... couldn't you just match digits at the end of the line and ignore the first group altogether? `/(\d*)$/`

Comment: yep, that should be the case. it's a best we can do proposition kind of thing, it doesn't have to be very exact. :)

Answer (score 1):

Satisfies all cases

`^(?=\d|.*\d$)((?:(?!\d+$).)*)(\d*)$`

https://regex101.com/r/BWwsIA/1

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?= \d | .* \d $ )            # Must begin or end with digit
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:                           # Cluster begin
           (?! \d+ $ )                   # Not digits then end
           .                             # Any char
      )*                            # Cluster end, 0 to many times
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( \d* )                       # (2)
 $                             # EOS
```